# How to store an sql result in a variable to be used

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, null, getstring

Good day all,

I am working on a java project, in netbeans.
I have a class called `dbcon`, which has a bunch of methods and a constructor that connects to a Mysql database.
One such method is a login method, which receives 2 parameters: username and password; searches the database using sqls and stores the result in a resultset. I then go on to use `getString` to retrieve the stored data and store it in a String variable. However, it returns a null value. The datatype in the table for username and password are both varchar(45). I had gotten the `mem_id` value before and was able to perform inserts using it appropriately, but have issues with the string type. Furthermore, the member variable `susername` also returns null even though I'm storing it directly from the passed variable username.

```
 public boolean login(String username, String pwd) throws SQLException {
        boolean res = false;
        String spass;
        try {
            ResultSet dbuser = stmt.executeQuery("select userpwd.mem_id, upassword, email from userpwd, memdet"
                    + " where userpwd.username = '" + username + "' and memdet.mem_id=userpwd.mem_id");
            if (dbuser.next()) {
                spass = dbuser.getString("upassword");
                if ((spass.equals(pwd))) {
                    res = true;
                    id = dbuser.getInt("mem_id");
                    this.susername = username;
                    this.semail = dbuser.getString("email");
                } else {
                    res = false;
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: In my opinion, the login method should only verify if the username and password are correct. Use a different method to retrieve "mem_id".

Comment: Also, I am guessing that the goal is to get the email. If so, I could guess that you can do one query to retrieve the email where the tables are joined on "mem_id".

Comment: Also, What does `if ((dbuser.next()` do? I am referring to the second time you call it.

Comment: @SedJ601, so, i first created the second instance of ```if(dbuser.next()```  to verify that there is a password value present in the record that matches the username, and later on added in the first instance to verify that there is no null value in the record.

Comment: @OR13N __This code is a security leak__. What if the user picks as name, say, `bobby tables'; DROP TABLE userpwd CASCADE; EXEC 'FORMAT C: /Y'; --`? You _must_ use `PreparedStatement` unless your entire SQL string is a constant or at least constructed from entirely input from within your app, not anything outside of your control.

Comment: @rzwitserloot, you are correct, however this project is a personal one and will be operated only by myself and 2 others, as such i did not see it necessary(although bad practice) to use a prepped statement

Comment: @OR13N Projects tend to either fall into the 'serious' or 'to learn' camp. Using styles that lead to obvious security holes are unsuitable for either usage. Hence, this is just bad code, and 'its just for personal use' isnt a good reason for it. More to the point, Stack Overflow isn't a 'help me' kind of site. It's a 'repository of common questions with useful answers' kind of site; questions are meant to be useful for everybody, not just you.

Comment: serialize(), json, $_SESSION[], etc can help you cobble together some of what you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The second call to `dbuser.next()` is making the result set to advance, so that `if` body doesn't enter, you don't need that, just move the `if` inside the other.

Like:

```java
 public boolean login(String username, String pwd) throws SQLException {
    boolean res = false;
    String spass="";
    try {
        ResultSet dbuser = stmt.executeQuery("select password from userpwd where username = '" + username + "';"); //here you should use parameters to set the username.
        if (dbuser.next()){
            spass = dbuser.getString("password");
            if (spass.equals(pwd)) {
                res = true;
                ResultSet mid = stmt.executeQuery("select mem_id from userpwd where username = '" + username + "';");
                id = mid.getInt("mem_id");
                this.susername = username;
                ins = "select email from memdet where mem_id = " + id;
                ResultSet ema = stmt.executeQuery(ins);
                this.semail = ema.getString("email");
            } else {
                res = false;
            }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
    return res;
}
```

There are lots of other things to be improved like, using parameters for setting the query parameters, to avoid SQL injection attacks, and there is no need to perform three queries, you could do it with one and a join.

Comment: thank you for your input! i have improved the code and it works! Also this is a personal project with only 3 handlers, so although it is bad code practice i did not use parameters as there is no reason for it